# Invalid Syntax calling "print" attribute

Tags: python

This is the response received from third party API

> response =    [{
>          print = True
>       },{print = False}]

Now if I access the "print" attribute of that response, it give me with syntax error

```
for res in response:
    print res.print
```

> SyntaxError('invalid syntax',
>   '/home/suman/workspace/kioskinterface/apis/igt.py', 104, 38, '
>   print ticket.print\n')

The problem must be because of the reserved word. Is there any way around to access "print" attribute from the response.

Comment: maybe `res['print']`?

Comment: awesome. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `getattr`:

```
print getattr(res, 'print')
```